# Combine these two sentence with relative pronoun

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses

Can I combine these two sentences:

1. I'll never forget the time.
2. We were a happy couple then.

To

> I'll never forget the time that we were a happy couple.

And more, without "that"

> I'll never forget the time we were a happy couple.

I remember we can use a sentence to describe the objective.

Comment: I have certainly heard it - and I would *guess* that this is a result of the ellipsis "the time when we..." -> "the time we..." and then back-formation. I tend to hear it more used when "time" means "(one) occasion (out of several)" rather than "point in time", but I've heard both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, "I will never forget the time when we were a happy couple."

Comment: I would probably just say "I will never forget when we were a happy couple." But +1.

Answer (score 0):

The snag is that there is more than a hint of a one-off occasion, as in

> I'll never forget the time a wheel came off the car and rolled past us along the highway.

(I hadn't intended that pun!)

I'd suggest:

> I'll never forget the time we had / when we were together - we made such a happy couple!

Comment: So, it's not wrong at all,but hard to be read? 
And, I want to eliminate - we made such a happy couple...
Any alternative?

Comment: Every time a word gets left out, some situational meanings may get excluded and some others may become prominent because of arbitrary idiom formation. Half the questions in EL&U get asked because people are trying to understand how to handle such extremely reduced clauses. Better to leave things in if clarity is an objective, as well as being "correct".